# Power Query - compare date versus today as boolean

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have a column that contains dates.
Is there any function to get TRUE/ FALSE if the date is before TODAY()?

Answer (score 5):

to check if date column is before today's date,

add column .. custom column ..

```
= [yourdatecolumnname] < DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())
```

to test if equal to todays date

```
 = [yourdatecolumnname] = DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())

 or 

 =  Date.IsInCurrentDay([yourdatecolumnname])
```

to test if equal to yesterdays date

```
 = Date.IsInPreviousDay([yourdatecolumnname])

 or

= [yourdatecolumnname] < Date.AddDays(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()),-1)
```